# How do I use the switchClass with img tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I can't get switchClass working for my images. I have 2 switchClass calls. The one for the text fires fine but the one for the img does nothing but switch the class (no visual changes).

I have a demo [here](http://jsbin.com/razibowi/1/edit?html,css,js,output)  (jsFiddle wouldn't work for this example...)

```
// Item Hover effects
$("div.cage > div.item").on("mouseenter", function (e) {
    // img
    $(this)
        .children('a')
        .children('img').stop(true, true)
        .addClass("network-img-state-default").switchClass("network-img-state-default", "network-img-state-hover", 200, 'easeInOutQuad');

    /* works but not ideal as I have media tags for dimensions        $(this).children('a').children('img').stop().animate({ "height": '299', "left": '0', "top": '0', "width": '450'}, 200, 'easeInOutQuad');
     */

    // h2
    $(this)
        .children('a')
        .children('h2').stop(true, true)
        .switchClass("network-state-default", "network-state-hover", 200, 'easeInOutQuad'); // End h2
}).on("mouseleave", function (e) {
    // img 
    $(this)
        .children('a')
        .children('img').stop(true, true)
        .switchClass("network-img-state-hover", "network-img-state-default", 200, 'easeInOutQuad');

    /* works        $(this).children('a').children('img').stop().animate({ "height": '332', "left": '-20', "top": '-20', "width": '500'}, 200, 'easeInOutQuad');
     */

    // h2
    $(this)
        .children('a')
        .children('h2').stop(true, true)
        .switchClass("network-state-hover", "network-state-default", 200, 'easeInOutQuad'); // End h2
});
```

The img should zoom out on hover. I have animate code commented out that works (so you can see the effect I am going for) but I am wanting to use classes for media queries.

Hoping it's something small I missed. Any insight is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: actually your commented code does not work. At least on chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Answer

You have a style overriding your class:

```css
.item a img {
    width: 500px;
    height: 332px;
    max-width: none;
}
```

This style has a higher specificity than just `.network-img-state-hover` so it gets applied instead.  Change the hover selector from `.network-img-state-hover` to:

```css
.item a img.network-img-state-hover {
    ...
}
```

http://jsbin.com/nejowaqe/1/edit

---

### Bonus tip

You could go a step further and eliminate the default state classes and use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` instead of `.switchClass()`.  Take it further still by using `.hover()` and `.toggleClass()` and you then can use one function for both mouseenter and mouseleave:

http://jsbin.com/nejowaqe/3/edit

---

### Taking my answer too far  ;-)

You can also do it with **no JavaScript at all** by using [CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions).  After you delete your JavaScript, replace your hover classes with selectors that use the `:hover` pseudo-class and add the `transition` properties to your existing styles:

```css
.item a img {
    /* ... existing styles ... */
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition-property: width, height, left, top;
}
.item a h2 {
    /* ... existing styles ... */
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition-property: padding-top, background-color, opacity;
}
.item:hover a img {
    /* ... existing styles ... */
}
.item:hover a h2 {
    /* ... existing styles ... */
}
```

http://jsbin.com/nejowaqe/4/edit

Of course, that doesn't work in IE9 or earlier, so if you need to support those browsers, stick with the jQuery approach.

Comment: Just a heads-up to anyone else having this issue. An easier fix was to prefix the states the way I did the default image, using `.item a img`. I couldn't remove the default `.item a img` as this was needed to fix the image offset to spoof the zoom effect. ie: `.item a img.network-img-state-default` You can see the working version here: http://jsbin.com/razibowi/8/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Classes toggling is fine. There is an CSS problem. You have:

```
.item a img {
    width: 500px;
    height: 332px;
    max-width: none;
}
```

Then:

```
.network-img-state-default {
    width: 500px;
    height: 332px;
    left: -20px;
    top: -20px;
}
```

And finally:

```
.network-img-state-hover {
    width: 450px;
    height: 299px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

`.item a img` have higher priority than other 2 classes so browser uses `width: 500px;` and `height: 332px;` in any case. Classes toggling works fine. Use `.item a img.your_class_name` for both of default and hover classes.

Comment: I accepted the answer that explained in more detail for other users. Nice find and thanks for your help.